# Yii cant validate file input

Tags: php, forms, validation, file-upload, yii

I'm currently doing a project in PHP Yii Framework. I have a form which requires the user to upload a file. During the registration, user uploaded the file, however, when user submits the form, the form is always detected blank on the file input, it's like as if there is no attachment on the form. below is the code:

Model - CandidateResume:

```
return array(           
      array('resume_file','file','types'=>'doc,docx,pdf', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'safe'=>true, 'on'=>'register'),
);
```

Model - Candidate:

```
return array(
      array('can_email,name,repeat_can_email, can_password,repeat_can_password','required', 'on'=>'simplereg'),
);
```

View:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
    'id'=>'candidate-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'type'=>'horizontal',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'autocomplete'=>'off', //turn off auto complete in FF
    )
)); 

echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'can_email',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>100)); 
echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'repeat_can_email',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>100)); 
echo $form->passwordFieldRow($model,'can_password',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>100)); 
echo $form->passwordFieldRow($model,'repeat_can_password',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>100)); 
echo $form->fileFieldRow($resume,'resume_file', array('id'=>'resume_file'));  

$this->endWidget();
```

Controller - Candidate:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Candidate();
    $model->setScenario('simplereg');
    $resume = new CandidateResume();
    $resume->setScenario('register');   

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    //$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Candidate'], $_POST['CandidateResume']))
    {
        $_POST['CandidateResume']['resume_file'] = $resume->resume_file;
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Candidate'];
        $resume->attributes = $_POST['CandidateResume'];

        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($resume,'resume_file');          

        if($resume->validate() && $model->validate()) 
        {
            $model->save();

            if(!empty($uploadedFile))  // check if uploaded file is set or not
            {
                $saved = $uploadedFile->saveAs(Yii::app()->params['RESUME_PATH'].$model->can_id.'_'.$uploadedFile->getName());
                $resume->resume_file = Yii::app()->params['RESUME_DIR'].$model->can_id.'_'.$uploadedFile->getName();
                $resume->resume_send_ip = Yii::app()->request->userHostAddress;
            }
            $resume->save();

        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model, 'resume'=>$resume));
}
```

If I remove the validation on the controller:

```
if($resume->validate() && $model->validate())
```

The form data can be saved and attachment is placed properly in the folder. However, I need to do the validation for the form. Therefore I cant skip this part.

Is there anything that I missed out? I have checked many times and do researches for the solutions. All provides the similar solutions, therefore I can't figure out the things. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the `resume_file` attribute. It cames from `$_FILES` not from `$_POST`

```
$resume->attributes = $_POST['CandidateResume'];
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($resume,'resume_file');   
$resume->resume_file = $uploadedFile; //add this line
```

Comment: Where should I add the line? before or after validation?

Comment: Before `validate()` method after initialization of `$uploadedFile`

Comment: Thank you! it works!! I have struggled with this error for so long and cant find the answer, and it turns out because of that line. Can I know why we need to have that assignment before validation? I thought it should be able to detect by itself.

Comment: Because `$resume->attributes = $_POST['CandidateResume'];` don't set the `resume_file` attribute. <input type="file"> transforms into superglobal array `$_FILES` not in `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc

Comment: I realize another thing is that form data is saved inside the db if I use: $model->save(); I need to put false inside the bracket. why? Is there a difference?

Comment: Argument in save() function to check validation on saving time or not. By default, it's validating. So it's wise to call validate() and save(FALSE).